# Flattening a list of lists in a Kusto Query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a Kusto query that returns a series of rows, each containing a semicolon delimited list. I have been able to split the contents of each row into a list, but I haven't been able to flatten that list. Unfortunately, I'm quite new to using Kusto, so I'm struggling a bit.

I've tried using the functions "union," "join," "flatten," and looking for functions that include the word "merge" or "selectmany" (the function I would use to flatten in c# with linq). I've also tried searching for similar sql functions, so I can look up the equivalent query in Kusto, but I haven't had any luck.

I'm using the query:

```
| where Nicknames != ""
| project split(Nicknames, ";")
```

The results are something like this:

```
[
"Joe",
"Jim",
"JJ"
]
-------------
[
"Abe"
]
-------------
[
"Hal",
"Harry"
]
```

and I'd like to use something like (psudo-Kusto):

```
UserInfo
| where Nicknames != ""
| project split(Nicknames, ";")
| flatten results
| distinct results
```

...where "results" are the tables returned by the previous operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [mv-expand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) operator, for example

```
datatable(Nicknames:string)["Joe;Jim;JJ", "Abe", "Hal;Harry"] 
| extend Nicknames = split(Nicknames, ";")
| mv-expand Nicknames to typeof(string)
| distinct Nicknames
```